# Symmetric half-band FIR re-timing

Tags: finite-impulse-response, symmetry

I'm trying to get my head around an FPGA implementation of a half-band FIR filter. I'm trying to draw the block diagram to help with that. I've started with a 10th order example as so:
[image]

Due to the filter being a half-band, I can remove the zero taps:
[image]

The delays can then be grouped:
[image]

There is symmetry in the coefficients:
[image]

Folding the delay path to take advantage of the symmetry:
[image]

Now I want to re-time the filter to pipeline the adder chain. This is the part i'm unsure about. I've added the registers to the adder chain. Do I increase the left-to-right delay taps by 1 and decrease the right-to-left taps by 1? Or, due to removing the zero'd out taps do they have to increase and decrease by 2 (apart from around the centre tap which will increase/decrease by 1)?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Looking at an example in some course notes I have, this is what I thought would've have been the result of using the cut-set method:

[image]

You add a delay on the inbound path (left-to-right) and remove a delay from the folded delay path. This looks to be still a causal solution to me.

Comment: I think you will have to add more detail on what exactly "retiming" and "pipelining" means in your case. I assume that the adders have some non-zero latency but I'm not sure.

Comment: As this is being implemented in an FPGA, as the order of the filter gets larger, the adder chain along the bottom becomes the limiting factor as to how fast you can clock the filter. I'm trying to add pipelining to that chain by adding registers between the additions. I know you can do this using the cut-set method but i'm struggling to apply it on the folded structure i'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has updated the question with a possible solution and asks about causality and filter equivalence. Note first the transfer function for the intended linear phase filter with symmetric coefficients given as:

$$H(z) = w_0 + w_2z^{-2} + w_4z^{-4} + w_5z^{-5} + w_4z^{-6} +w_2z^{-8} + w_0z^{-10} $$

The third filter structure that the OP has given has a transfer function given as:

$$H(z) = w_0z^{-3} + w_2z^{-5} + w_4z^{-7} + w_5z^{-8} + w_4z^{-9} + w_2z^{-11} + w_0z^{-13}$$

Factoring out the additional 3 sample delay results in an otherwise perfect (and causal) match:

$$H(z) = z^{-3}(w_0 + w_2z^{-2} + w_4z^{-4} + w_5z^{-5} + w_4z^{-6} + w_2z^{-8} + w_0z^{-10})$$

Nice job Adi, I couldn't see the way without your help.

Below are additional other suggestions for meeting timing from my earlier answer for comparison to the OP's good suggestion above.

Below is a retimed linear phase filter using a synchronous adder-tree:

[image: retimed]

An alternate approach would be to reverse the flow diagram (all branches become summing notes and summing nodes become branches, and signal flow is in reverse). This would result in a register at the output of each adder with a functionally equivalent filter and would look like the following:

[image: reverse flow diagram]

Note that the first approach results in an additional delay while the second approach would be identical to the original.

---

Comment: The FIR cores from AMD and Intel usually perform pre-adding to reduce the number of multipliers just like you did. And there's usually a pipelining delay of anywhere from 1 to 4 clock cycles. So your first solution is pretty close to what AMD and Intel do.

Comment: @Ben thank you- what is your experience / opinion with the second option? I like that it doesn’t introduce additional delay (when we care)

Comment: it doesn't introduce additional delay. That being said, It could be hard to meet timing closure. Remember adding pipelining delays to an FIR described by H(Z) is mathematically like multiplying H(z)*z^-N where N is the pipelining delay.

Comment: Ah due to the pipelining with a clock cycle (4 1/4 sample delays)? So what about the second option when timing is challenging?

Comment: What I mean is that your first solution, the FIR transfer function has been transformed from H(z) to H(z)*z^-2 since you added 2 pipeline delays in the adder chain. It is usually needed if one wants to run an FIR at 100 MHz and more.

Obviously if the FIR runs at 1 MHz, there is no need for pipeline delays to meet timing closure. But then you probably don't need an FPGA if your FIR has a low sampling rate.

Comment: That is what I first meant about additional delay (z^(-2) is a 2 sample delay)—- what about the your thoughts on the second approach? There is no delay and should meet timing.

Comment: Yes since you have only 8 taps, it will likely work. However, if you had 64 taps, it would be hard to meet timing closure without additional pipeline delays.

Comment: @Ben but there are no accumulated delays— it could be 1000 taps yet it is one clock cycle per adder before it is retimed!

Comment: Yeah you're right. I would have to look at the internals of the FPGA MAC blocks to see why this approach is not widely used.

Comment: Thanks both for your input.  The first approach I have come across similar architectures, it does add some extra latency but probably not a massive issue for my target application. The second approach could get difficult to get to meet timing in an FPGA as the number of taps increase due to the broadcast of the input going to each of the taps. The tools may help here assuming the input to the filter was from a bunch of registers and therefore register duplication could take place. I've updated my original post with what I believe is a valid solution. Any comments on that appreciated.

Comment: Yes indeed it looks like you figured it out! I added the confirmation to my answer. As to the reverse flow approach, you are broadcasting the input to multiple multiplier inputs but note how you have the time of 2 cycles in all but the first one for the output of a single multiplier summation to be valid, with no further combinatorial delay which makes it very robust for meeting timing. So you essentially have the time of 2 clock cycles to align that broadcast which doesn't seem like it would be challenging (compared to the accumulation in an adder tree)  Do you see something I don't?

Comment: Thanks @DanBoschen, I guess you are correct in that you do mostly have multiple clock cycles for the multiply summation in the reverse flow architecture. I'd probably avoid this approach in my FPGA designs just for keeping the timing constraints as straight forward as possible unless latency was a key factor in-which case the slightly more complicated timing constraints may be worth it.